# Ошибка с Executor из aiogram python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher 
from aiogram.utils import Executor

import os

bot = Bot(token = os.getenv('TOKEN'))
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()

async def echo_send(message : types.Message):

        await message.answer(message.text)
        # await message.reply(message.text)
        # await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message.text)

executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates = True)
```

Ошибка в:

```
from aiogram.utils import Executor

ImportError: cannot import name 'Executor' from 'aiogram.utils'
```

Comment: поместите код согласно правилам для начала. Ещё желательно пояснить, что именно непонятно в ошибке?

Answer (score 0):

Делай так

```
from aiogram import executor
```